Conditioning type on an enum
I have two functions for accessing database and getting a post with all associated comments, etc. One returns the normal version of the post, and another returns the version containing sensitive information only the creator of the post should see (such as engagement metrics). The code for the two functions is almost identical, so I would ideally like to condence them into one function to reduce boilerplate. To do so, I need a way to condition the return type; from what I understand currently the only way to do that is to use types conditioned on another type like so:
type A = {a: number);
type B = {b: number);

func getpost(id: number, condition: T extends A | B) : T extends A ? normalPost : protectedPost 

Question is, can I do this in a less derived way? Something like using enum for condition would look a lot cleaner than what I have above, maybe something like
enum AccessLevel = {normal, protected}

func getpost(id: number, accessLevel: AccessLevel) : accessLevel=protected ? protectedPost : normalPost


It would help if this was a [mre] and not just pseudocode.  Things like func and undeclared generic type parameters only make your question harder to understand.  Please [edit] to make sure at least the “like so” code compiles without error.

@jcalz on a second look. I don't think the first code block can be implemented in TypeScript either. The crux of my question is that I have two very similar functions that return similar objects, where one object extends the other. I would like to have a way to combine them into one function that has an extra input that "parametrises" which of the two output modes I want to receive.

Okay, but that means you should definitely [edit] the question to ask what you mean to ask without distracting pseudocode.  {a: number) is , as is enum AccessLevel =. I took your top example and debugged it to this version. I assume that's what you mean, but I can't know for sure until and unless this becomes a [mre].

(see prev comment) if my code matches what you're trying to do, perhaps this approach is what you're looking for. If so I could write that up as an answer after you [edit] the question accordingly. If not, what am I missing?
